# How to Use array[i] in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to search for a value in an array. Does the array need a definative number? How would I search for the number? Thanks for helping!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"


using namespace std;
int main() {
    int userinput;

    int arrayofnumber[10] = { 5, 3, 77, 43, 6, 22, 7, 9, 84, 26 };

    int NumberInArray = sizeof(arrayofnumber) / sizeof(arrayofnumber[0]);

    cout << "What Number Would You Like To Search For? \n";
    cout << "Number of Values in Array = " << NumberInArray << endl;
    cin >> userinput;

    for (int i = 0; i >= NumberInArray; i++) {

        if (userinput == NumberInArray[i]) {
            cout << "We Found IT! It = " << NumberInArray[i] << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't run because the condition `i>=NumberInArray` is false from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberInArray; i++) {
    if (userinput == arrayofnumber[i]) {
        cout << "We Found IT! It = " << arrayofnumber[i] << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Your `for` loop condition `i >= NumberInArray` is wrong. It should be `i < NumberInArray`.

`NumberInArray[i]` is illegal. You should do `arrayofnumber[i]`.

Added `break` so that when the number is found, you can get out of the loop.

Comment: `break;` is just for increasing the efficiency of your code, if you have not learned this C++ keyword yet, you can ignore it for now

Answer (score 1):

The standard provides us with [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to do this. So I'd suggest using C++'s implementation rather than trying to write it yourself, doing so will also eliminate your need for `NumberInArray`:

```
if(cend(arrayofnumber) != find(cbegin(arrayofnumber), cend(arrayofnumber), userinput)) cout << "We Found IT! It = " << userinput << endl;
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/Wge0lv)